# Combinatorial total space for finitely generated torsion-free groups?

Tags: group-theory, metric-spaces, operator-algebras, geometric-group-theory, noncommutative-geometry

**Motivation**: I'm an operator algebraist and I'm looking for an answer to the *main question* in order to build *non-trivial* [spectral triples](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_triple) for a class (as large as possible) of discrete groups.
$\to$ It's *[noncommutative geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncommutative_geometry)* "à la Alain Connes".

**Definition** : Let $G$ be a group, then a *total space* for $G$ is a *[weakly contractible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_contractible)* topological space $X$ (i.e., every [homotopy groups](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_group) $\pi_{n}(X)$ are trivial), together with a *free action* of $G$ (i.e, $\forall x \in X$ and $\forall g \in G$, if $g.x = x$ then $g = e$). It is generally noted $EG$.

**Definition** : A group $\Gamma$ is [finitely generated](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_set_of_a_group#Finitely_generated_group) if there is a finite generating subset $S \subset \Gamma $.
In general such groups can be defined by generators $S$ and  relations $R$, as $\Gamma := \langle S \hspace{0.1cm} \vert \hspace{0.1cm} R \rangle$.
The pair $(\Gamma , S)$ is called a *marked group*.

**Definition**: Let $(\Gamma , S)$  be a marked group with $|S| < \infty$ (i.e. finitely generated), $S=S^{-1}$ and identity $e \not \in S$. Let $\Gamma_{n}$ be the sets of **irreducible $n$-blocks**, defined by induction as follows:

- $\Gamma_{0} := \Gamma$,
- $\Gamma_{1}:=\{ \{ g ,gs \}  \hspace{0.1cm}   \vert \hspace{0.1cm}    g \in \Gamma, s \in S  \}$,
- for $n \geq 2$, a $n$-block is a nonempty finite set $\mathfrak{a}$ of irreducible $(n-1)$-blocks such that
  $$ \forall \mathfrak{b} \in \mathfrak{a}, \forall \mathfrak{c} \in \mathfrak{b}, \exists ! \mathfrak{b}'\in \mathfrak{a}  \text{ such that }  \mathfrak{b} \cap \mathfrak{b}' = \{\mathfrak{c}\};$$
  it is called *irreducible* if for all $n$-blocks $ \mathfrak{a}_1$ and $\mathfrak{a}_2$
  $$ \mathfrak{a} = \mathfrak{a}_1 \triangle \mathfrak{a}_2 := (\mathfrak{a}_1 \cup \mathfrak{a}_2) \backslash \mathfrak{a}_1 \cap \mathfrak{a}_2 \Rightarrow  max(\vert \mathfrak{a}_1 \vert ,\vert \mathfrak{a}_2\vert) \ge \vert \mathfrak{a}\vert. $$

**Geometric realization**: Let $\Gamma$ be a finitely generated *marked* group, and let $\Gamma_{n}$ its set of *irreducible* $n$-blocks. Its geometric realization $X$ is the topological space built by induction :
Each element $\mathfrak{a}$ of $\Gamma_{n}$ is related to a $n$-polytope $r(\mathfrak{a}) \subset X$  as follows :

- $\mathfrak{a} \in \Gamma_{0}$ is related to a  vertex.
- $\mathfrak{a} \in \Gamma_{1}$ is related to an edge.
- $\mathfrak{a} \in \Gamma_{2}$ is related to the regular polygon with $\vert \mathfrak{a} \vert$ edges.
- $\mathfrak{a} \in \Gamma_{n+1}$ is related to the $(n+1)$-polytope, obtained  as the (n+1)-dimensional filling of the gluing of the $\vert \mathfrak{a} \vert$ $n$-polytopes related to the elements of $\mathfrak{a}$, such that $\forall \mathfrak{b}, \mathfrak{b}' \in \mathfrak{a}$ then: $r(\mathfrak{b} \cap \mathfrak{b}') = r(\mathfrak{b}) \cap  r(\mathfrak{b}')$.

**Definition** : Let  $X_{n}$ be the [regular CW complex](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479026/is-a-cw-complex-homeomorphic-to-a-regular-cw-complex) obtained by gluing together all these $m$-polytopes  $\forall m \leq n$ such that $\forall \mathfrak{a}, \mathfrak{a}' \in \Gamma_{m}$ then $r(\mathfrak{a} \cap \mathfrak{a}') = r(\mathfrak{a}) \cap  r(\mathfrak{a}')$.

Note that the [Cayley graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley_graph) is $X_{1}$, and the [Cayley complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_complex) is "close" to $X_{2}$.

Each $X_{n}$ admits a natural distance $d_{n}$, and $X_{n-1}$ naturally embeds into $X_{n}$.

**Definition** : Let $d$ be the distance on $ \bigcup{X_{n}}$, defined as follows :   $d(x,y) = \lim_{n \to \infty} d_{n}(x,y)$.

**Remark** : There is a small abuse in the previous definition because $d_{n}(x,y)$ is defined only for $x, y \in X_{n}$. But because we take $n \to \infty$, there is no problem.

**Definition** : Let $X:=\overline{\bigcup{X_{n}}}$, the *complete metric space* obtained as a [completion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson_groups) of $\bigcup{X_{n}}$ for $d$. We call it the **total Cayley space** of the pair $(\Gamma, S)$.

> **Main question** : Is the total Cayley space $X$ of a finitely generated marked group $(\Gamma, S)$, a total space $E \Gamma$, for $\Gamma$ torsion-free ?

**Dimension** :

- if $\Gamma_{n} \neq \emptyset$ and $\Gamma_{n+1}  = \emptyset $, then $X$ is an $n$-dimensional topological space and  $X \simeq X_{n}$.
- if $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ then $\Gamma_{n} \neq \emptyset$, then $X$ is an $\infty$-dimensional topological space.
  $\to$ The [Thompson group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thompson_groups) $F$  (see B. Steinberg comment below).

---

**Sketch of proof** (*it needs to be completed*)

*Finite dimensional case:*

- The natural action of $\Gamma$ on $X$ is *free*.
  Let $x \in X$ and $g \in G$ such that $g.x = x$, then $\exists n \geq 0$ and $\mathfrak{a} \in \Gamma_{n}$ such that $x \in r(\mathfrak{a})$ and $g.\mathfrak{a} = \mathfrak{a}$. So a finite subset of $\Gamma$ is stable under the left multiplication by $g$, then $g$ is torsion, so $g=e$ by assumption. $\square$
- $X$ is *weakly contractible*:
  By construction, an embedding of a sphere $\mathbb{S}^{n-1}$ is homotopic to the border of the realization $r(\mathfrak{a})$ of an irreducible $n$-block $\mathfrak{a}$. Now $r(\mathfrak{a})$ is a polytope, so it's homotopic to a point,  its border also. $\square$

*$\infty$-dimensional case:*

- The natural action of $\Gamma$ on $X$ is *free* (inspired by Andreas Thom) :
  Let $x \in X$ and $g \in G$ such that $g.x = x$. Now, $x = [(x_{n})]_{\sim}$ and $g.x = [(g.x_{n})]_{\sim}$, so $d_{n}(x_{n},g.x_{n}) \to 0$. Let $n$ with $d_{n}(x_{n},g.x_{n})$ *sufficiently small*, and let $\mathfrak{a}, \mathfrak{a'}\in \Gamma_{n}$ such that $x_{n} \in r(\mathfrak{a})$ and $g.x_{n} \in r(\mathfrak{a'})$. By construction, $r(\mathfrak{a}) \cap r(\mathfrak{a'}) \ne \emptyset$ and $\exists r \le n$, $\mathfrak{b} \in \Gamma_{r}$ such that $r(\mathfrak{b}) \subset r(\mathfrak{a}) \cap r(\mathfrak{a'})$ and $g.\mathfrak{b} = \mathfrak{b}$. The result follows as previously. $\square$
- $X$ is *weakly contractible* ? See the generalized post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/566542/84284).

---

In the literature $E \Gamma$ is well known as the universal covering of the classifying space $B \Gamma$, which is (in the discrete groups case) the [Eilenberg-MacLane space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93MacLane_space) $K(\Gamma , 1)$. There is also the [Milnor construction](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/1970012?uid=3738016&uid=2129&uid=2&uid=70&uid=4&sid=21102544344997).
The construction here, specific to finitely generated groups, is very *combinatorial*.

> **Question** : Is there a good reference containing  this combinatorial construction ?

Comment: Have you read the paper of Baumslag-Bridson-Miller-Short on fibre products, non-positive curvature and decision problems? I *think* they cover some of this stuff in their 1-2-3 theorem, but I didn't quite understand all of your question. (It is not your fault, it is because I'm lazy. Sorry.)

Comment: @user1729 : thank you very much for this reference. I will look at it right now. Note that I know Hamish Short, he was my professor of geometric group theory when I was student. Maybe I can ask him.

Comment: A question on the geometric realization:  How do you know the $(n+1)$ dimensional filling is unique, or indeed even exists?  For example, what if one of your 3-blocks is a collection of 2-blocks that form a Klein bottle?

Comment: @MartianInvader : Nice comment ! First of all, I need to prove that the $n$-blocks are orientable (or to find a counter-example, and restrict to the groups for which the n-blocks are orientable). I will think more about that.

Comment: I think you need more than orientability - it sounds like you want your $n$-blocks to become cells in a CW-complex, which means they need to not only be orientable, but be $(n-1)$ spheres.

Comment: @MartianInvader : Thank you for this comment. Do you have in mind an example of finitely generated group, admitting non-orientable *irreducible* $n$-blocks, or orientable *irreducible* $n$-blocks but not homeomorphic to $\mathbb{S}^{n−1}$ ? And do you know a large class of groups for which it's always verified ?

Comment: I can't come up with an example off the top of my head, and I suspect you would need to go beyond a $3$-block to find one.  To prove it in 3 dimensions, I would try a strategy like the following: since a non-sphere surface will have nontrivial fundamental group, we can find a loop that's not nullhomotopic, which will necessarily be a 2-block on its own, and we can use such 2-blocks to subdivide the surface, showing it's not irreducible.  This argument won't work in general, though, since higher-dimensional non-sphere manifolds can have trivial $(n-1)$-homotopy groups.

Comment: @MartianInvader : Very interesting comment ! So for the groups whose space $X$ is of dimension $\le 3$, then 'maybe' it's ok (it's already a large class of groups). Next, for dimension $>3$, more works are expectable.