# Is such an infinite dimensional metric space, weakly contractible?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, metric-spaces, homotopy-theory, geometric-topology

We counteract this [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/142529/a-problem-on-infinite-dimensional-metric-space/143837#143837) by adding the *rigidity assumption*: Is there still a counterexample?

Let $(X_{n},d_{n})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of complete [geodesic metric spaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glossary_of_Riemannian_and_metric_geometry#G) such that:
 $X_{n}$ is a regular$^1$ [CW-complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CW_complex) of constant local dimension$^3$ $n$, it is of finite type$^4$, boundaryless$^2$, unbounded, uniform$^5$, and it is the $n$-skeleton of $X_{n+1}$, which is [n-connected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-connected). Moreover, the distances  $d_{n}$ , $d_{n+1}$ generate the same topology on $X_{n}$ and  $\forall x,y \in X_{n} \ d_{n+1}(x,y) \le d_{n}(x,y)$.
Finally $(X_{n},d_{n})$ is [quasi-isometric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quasi-isometry) to $(X_{n+1},d_{n+1})$, through the inclusion map $X_{n} \subset X_{n+1}$, and a distance $d$ on $ \bigcup{X_{n}}$ is defined (for $x, y \in X_{n_0}$) by    $d(x,y) := lim_{n (\ge n_0) \to \infty} d_{n}(x,y)$.

**Rigidity assumption**: if $S$ is a connected subspace of $X_{n}$ such that $S$ contains the geodesic paths between all its points, for $d_{n}$ **and** $d_{n+1}$, then $d_{n} = d_{n+1}$  on $S$.

*Definition* : Let $X:=\overline{\bigcup{X_{n}}}$ be the [completion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complete_space#Completion) of the metric space $\bigcup{X_{n}}$ with $d$.
**Question** : Is $X$ [weakly contractible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weakly_contractible) ?

*Remark:* Some of these conditions could be useless for a proof, and others, highly generalized.
*Motivation*: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/478588/a-combinatorial-total-space-for-torsion-free-finitely-generated-groups) for applications to *geometric group theory* and *noncommutative geometry*.

---

$^1$Regular (for a CW complex) : the attaching maps are homeomorphism (see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/479026/is-a-cw-complex-homeomorphic-to-a-regular-cw-complex)).
$^2$Boundaryless (for a regular CW complex) : the boundary of each closed cell is contained is the union of the boundaries of other closed cells.
$^3$Constant local dimension :  the topological dimension of all neighborhood of all point, is constant.
$^4$Finite type : finitely many $r$-cells ending in a fixed $(r-1)$-cell.
$^5$Uniform : For all $r$-cell $c_{1}$ and $c_{2}$, there is a neighborhood $n_{1}$ of $c_{1}$ and $n_{2}$ of $c_{1}$, such that $n_{1}$ is homeomorphic to $n_{2}$.